# B-spline interpolation of deformation field for images

Tags: python, image, registration, spline, bspline

I am currently registering some images with Python, but creating my own tool to do so, as the current registration techniques do not suit my goal. I want to estimate b-splines of a deformation field but I am having issues extending anything I read about it to 2d images.

I already have a list of points that are matched between two images, and the deformation field at the locations...I want to use b-splines to generalize the deformation field to every point in the image.

```
# Find control points in the image
# p is a vector 2xnumber of control points
p = find_control_points(live_im)

# Find deformation of control points
# d is 1xnumber of control points
d = det_best_match(mask_im, live_im, p)
```

I have an image that is NxN and control points p that are the locations in the image. I was thinking about using scipy.interpolate.BSpline but you already need t, c, k to provide to it. All the examples are in 1d, and I guess I have a 3d example. I cannot for the life of me figure anything out regarding the maths. Has anyone used this before or could see if this is even achieve-able with this function?

Answer (score 0):

For B-spline curves/surfaces, control points are not the points on the curve/surface. You sure you already know them just by comparing the distorted image with the original?

Comment: Ok, this is where I am getting very confused with the whole thing. By control points there I meant points where I am estimating the displacement. So I have some sample points in the image in which I have found the displacement vectors. I guess then I need to use a b-spline grid to interpolate those displacement vectors onto the nearby points and that is the bit that I am struggling to understand

Comment: @BrookeBurton It does seem to need spline interpolation, but using B-spline is overkill. Basically B-spline is just the generic representation of all splines with arbitrary order and segments, typically only useful in geometric modelling. IMO you can just use cubic spline interpolation for grids which is common in image warping. Computing the polynomial coefficients only requires sampled values.
Cubic spline can also be represented in B-spline/NURBS form, but it's just not necessary.